# How do I do multiple pairwise alignments from a FASTA file and print the percentage similarity?

Tags: biopython, pairwise

I want to multiple pairwise comparisons for every protein sequence contained in a FASTA file and then print the percentage sequence similarity (either an average or individually). I think I need to use itertools to create all of the combinations, align them and then probably divide the number of matches by the aligned sequence length to get the % sequence similarity but I am having trouble with the specific script I need to do this, preferably in biopython if possible. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

My answer does not involve *Biopython*, but since no other answer has been posted yet, I will post it anyway:

The bioinformatics package *Biotite* (https://www.biotite-python.org/), a package I am currently developing, would solve your problem using the following script:

```py
import numpy as np
import biotite
import biotite.sequence as seq
import biotite.sequence.io.fasta as fasta
import biotite.sequence.align as align
import biotite.database.entrez as entrez


# 5 example sequences (bacterial luciferase variants)
uids = [
    'Q7N575', 'P19839', 'P09140', 'P07740', 'P24113'
]
# Download these sequences as one file from NCBI
file_name = entrez.fetch_single_file(
    uids, biotite.temp_file("fasta"), db_name="protein", ret_type="fasta"
)

# Read each sequence in the file as 'ProteinSequence' object
fasta_file = fasta.FastaFile()
fasta_file.read(file_name)
sequences = list(fasta.get_sequences(fasta_file).values())

# BLOSUM62
substitution_matrix = align.SubstitutionMatrix.std_protein_matrix()
# Matrix that will be filled with pairwise sequence identities
identities = np.ones((len(sequences), len(sequences)))
# Iterate over sequences
for i in range(len(sequences)):
    for j in range(i):
        # Align sequences pairwise
        alignment = align.align_optimal(
            sequences[i], sequences[j], substitution_matrix
        )[0]
        # Calculate pairwise sequence identities and fill matrix
        identity = align.get_sequence_identity(alignment)
        identities[i,j] = identity
        identities[j,i] = identity

print(identities)
```

The output:

```
[[1.         0.97214485 0.62921348 0.84225352 0.59776536]
 [0.97214485 1.         0.62359551 0.85352113 0.60055866]
 [0.62921348 0.62359551 1.         0.61126761 0.85393258]
 [0.84225352 0.85352113 0.61126761 1.         0.59383754]
 [0.59776536 0.60055866 0.85393258 0.59383754 1.        ]]
```